# Openstack-Autopilot - Unable to "Boot from image(Creates new volume)" - Error

Tags: openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I have installed openstack with openstack-autopilot, trying to launch an instance with "Boot from image(Creates new volume)" option, but it gives me this error from nova-compute.log:

```
2016-01-19 11:00:15.541 141391 WARNING nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-f0274244-cf51-476d-b53c-ce77f5f1eda1 775ea332bfc647f092d57ecec9469f95 fb90a38f8340433f84b04ec4429dc9e3 - - -] [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7] Ignoring supplied device name: /dev/vda. Libvirt can't honour user-supplied dev names
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-f0274244-cf51-476d-b53c-ce77f5f1eda1 775ea332bfc647f092d57ecec9469f95 fb90a38f8340433f84b04ec4429dc9e3 - - -] [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7] Instance failed block device setup
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7] Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1738, in _prep_block_device
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     wait_func=self._await_block_device_map_created)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 476, in attach_block_devices
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     map(_log_and_attach, block_device_mapping)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 474, in _log_and_attach
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     bdm.attach(*attach_args, **attach_kwargs)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 383, in attach
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     availability_zone=av_zone)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/volume/cinder.py", line 385, in create
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     raise exception.InvalidInput(reason=e)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7] InvalidInput: Invalid input received: Invalid input received: Availability zone 'region1-1' is invalid. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-1490caf9-fae1-4f0a-86e4-835b3c30d370)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.397 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-f0274244-cf51-476d-b53c-ce77f5f1eda1 775ea332bfc647f092d57ecec9469f95 fb90a38f8340433f84b04ec4429dc9e3 - - -] [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7] Build of instance cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7 aborted: Block Device Mapping is Invalid.
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7] Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1905, in _do_build_and_run_instance
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     filter_properties)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2025, in _build_and_run_instance
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     'create.error', fault=e)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 195, in __exit__
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1996, in _build_and_run_instance
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     block_device_mapping) as resources:
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     return self.gen.next()
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2143, in _build_resources
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]     reason=e.format_message())
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7] BuildAbortException: Build of instance cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7 aborted: Block Device Mapping is Invalid.
2016-01-19 11:00:17.504 141391 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: cf84bf3e-a978-48ae-af49-5aa07abbd1b7]
```

cinder-api.log:

```
2016-01-19 11:00:09.912 28131 WARNING cinder.quota [req-077e678b-f676-4f5b-b24d-7d85438d1c3c - - - - -] Deprecated: Default quota for resource: backup_gigabytes is set by the default quota flag: quota_backup_gigabytes, it is now deprecated. Please use the default quota class for default quota.
2016-01-19 11:00:09.986 28131 WARNING cinder.quota [req-077e678b-f676-4f5b-b24d-7d85438d1c3c - - - - -] Deprecated: Default quota for resource: backups is set by the default quota flag: quota_backups, it is now deprecated. Please use the default quota class for default quota.
2016-01-19 11:00:17.301 28136 WARNING cinder.volume.api [req-073d486b-3b67-4cc5-b67f-729a605dcb94 - - - - -] Task 'cinder.volume.flows.api.create_volume.ExtractVolumeRequestTask;volume:create' (9957bda0-f188-42db-a275-1ce695281b78) transitioned into state 'FAILURE' from state 'RUNNING'
Failure: cinder.exception.InvalidInput: Invalid input received: Availability zone 'region1-1' is invalid.
2016-01-19 11:00:17.309 28136 WARNING cinder.volume.api [req-073d486b-3b67-4cc5-b67f-729a605dcb94 - - - - -] Task 'cinder.volume.flows.api.create_volume.ExtractVolumeRequestTask;volume:create' (9957bda0-f188-42db-a275-1ce695281b78) transitioned into state 'REVERTED' from state 'REVERTING'
2016-01-19 11:00:17.312 28136 WARNING cinder.volume.api [req-073d486b-3b67-4cc5-b67f-729a605dcb94 - - - - -] Flow 'volume_create_api' (0c1b341c-db96-4ae5-af31-e594ac31cda4) transitioned into state 'REVERTED' from state 'RUNNING'
```

These are the errors if I try to run as admin in the dashboard, if I run as a project owner I get this error in Horizon:

```
The requested instance cannot be launched. 
Requested volume exceeds quota: Available: 0, Requested: 1.
```

If I create a volume and attach an Image, and create Instance from that volume, I am able to launch an Instance.

From the log it seems it doesn't recognise the availability zone.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?  I've experienced the same thing while using the GUI and the user quota isn't the problem.

Comment: No, still an issue.. Have to use the workaround by creating a volume and mount an image to it. I created an issue at https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/829 hoping for some feedback there maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar thing when login to UI by demo account.  I also saw the quota for the project demo is fine.  but when I change the volume quota from 10 to 9 and save, I could create the instance well.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try this out and report back.

Comment: That did not work for me, still get `... aborted: Block Device Mapping is Invalid`